# How to session_encode in symfony without breaking it

Tags: php, symfony, encode

Using PHP session functions (like session_encode()) is discouraged, as it breaks many Symfony features (like security, flash messages, and CSRF protection).

My question is how should we encode the session variables in symfony then ?
I just want to encode array inside `_sf2_attributes` inside $_SESSION variable.

Is there a function that can encode in a format like `session_encode()` if passed a particular array?

Comment: Because `session_encode()` is just **returning** data, and depending on what you want to do with it and as far as you do not want to use `session_decode()` afterwards, I don't see anything wrong to use it. A little more context would be helpful though.

Comment: @BorisGuéry I'm using sensio labs to determine the code quality, this is what is suggested by sesio `Using PHP session functions (like session_encode() here) is discouraged, as it breaks many Symfony features (like security, flash messages, and CSRF protection).`
I was wondering if another function exist that can encode in this format given the array parameter? or i'll have to write one of my own.

Comment: I do not know where you go this automated warning, however, while it is probably worth a read, as I said, it depends on what you are trying to achieve. These warnings are not rules by themselves, but warning. Use it with caution. Why do you need to use this function and how are you going to use the data, that are the questions.

Comment: @BorisGuéry I've to send whatever data is there in session to another symfony application (for authentication purpose) i.e the rest api on the backend so I was sending the string that I got from session_encode() & decoding from the api side but need an alternative here.

Comment: I'm planning to use just serialize() & unserialize() rather than this headache. Does that have any drawback ?

Comment: Well, if you need to do a cross-system authentication, I seriously advise against this method. Your best bet is to ask a new question on how to implement such mechanism and/or look at OAuth or SSO. But playing with raw sessions as you plan to do for this purpose seems like a dangerous thing.